# Is the String.charAt() method fast enough to use again and again?

Tags: java, string

So in many of my programs, I use the `string.charAt()` method everywhere I need to instead of storing it in one character and using that character again and again. Is the `charAt()` method fast enough to just throw around everywhere? Here's an example if you didn't understand what I said:

```
String importantStr = "Very Important String";

if(importantStr.charAt(5) == 'I') {
    System.out.println(importantStr.charAt(5));
    System.out.println(importantStr.charAt(5) + "Hi");
    /*
    Stuff to do with importantStr.charAt(5);
    */
}
```

I don't know why you would want to do this, but the point is that I am calling `importantStr.charAt(5)` again and again. Would it save a significant amount of time to just store it into another character and use that?

Comment: Store it in a local variable and use that.

Comment: It will probably save time.  But the time saving will be a few nanoseconds which  typically won't be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out, let us look into the source code of `charAt`

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

`value` is a `char[]` and hence the last statement is `O(1)`. But, there are a couple of additional index bound checks. But still, it is a constant time operation and you shouldn't be bothered about it (unless you are measuring performance at a nanosecond level and concerned at CPU cycles level)

On the other hand storing the character in a local variable and reusing it may be more readable.

Answer (score -1):

In terms of time-complexity, `charAt()` is a constant-time operation. So, it shouldn't matter if you use it directly, or store it in a variable. Both will give `O(1)` time complexity.